# show that A and B are independent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence, conditional-independence

Given $P(A,B,C,D) = P(A)P(B)P(C|A,B)P(D|C)$ show that $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$

---

First one can write $P(A,B,C,D) = P(A,B)P(C,D|A,B) $ hence

$P(A,B)P(C,D|A,B) = P(A)P(B)P(C|A,B)P(D|C)$

$P(A,B) = \frac{P(A)P(B)P(C|A,B)P(D|C)}{P(C,D|A,B)}$

$P(A,B) = \frac{P(A)P(B)P(C|A,B)P(D|C)}{P(C|A,B)P(D|A,B,C)}$

$P(A,B) = \frac{P(A)P(B)P(D|C)}{P(D|A,B,C)}$

And I'm stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$p(D|A,B,C) = p(D|C)$, otherwise we couldn't decompose $p(A,B,C,D)$ like this in the first place.

This reduces the fraction to :

$p(A,B) = p(A)p(B)*\frac{p(D|C)}{p(D|C)} = p(A)p(B)$

Which is exactly what you wanted to show.

Comment: Even if that was right, the term P(C|A,B) still doesn't go away, right?

Comment: Third equation in the OP got rid of it already by this point.

Comment: Not sure which one is the third equation since OP didn't named them, but in the second-to-last equation I can see that there is a P(C|A,B) both in the numerator and the denominator. 

So, in the next equation (the last one) those two terms are gone because they canceled each other out.  But then, you are saying that p(D|A,B,C)=p(D|C)p(C|A,B), which if substituted in the last equation, will make p(C|A,B) reappear and stay in the denominator. Am I not seeing something?

Comment: I dont think p(D|A,B,C)=p(D|C)p(C|A,B) is correct

Comment: p(D|A,B,C) 
= p(A,B,C,D)/p(A,B,C) 
= p(A)p(B)p(C|A,B)p(D|C) / p(A,B)p(C|A,B)
= p(A) p(B) p(D|C) / p(A,B)

If p(A,B) = p(A) p(B) (wich is what I need to prove) than p(D|A,B,C)  = p(D|C).

Comment: You don't actually need to prove $p(A,B) = p(A)p(B)$ *verbatim*, at least by the original phrasing of the question. You just need to prove $p(A|B) = p(A)$ and $p(B|A) = p(B)$ to establish they are independent.

Comment: Looking at this again, I outsmarted myself; the conditional probability for C had been redundant there.